# Spring: How to define database config?

Tags: spring

I try to execute simple request to MySql database via jdbcTemplate but I have an error when framework load and parse xml file whicj define my datasource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_training"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value="pass"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringTrainingTemplate</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml /WEB-INF/jdbc-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and Controller that invoke it:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
private ExampleService exampleService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String details(Model model) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jdbc-config.xml");
    ExampleDao dao = (ExampleDao) context.getBean("ExampleDao");
    List<Application> list = dao.getAllApplications();

    model.addAttribute("application", list.get(0).getName());
    model.addAttribute("descriptionOfApplication", list.get(0).getDescription());

    return "details";
}
}

public class ExampleDao {

private String request = "select * from application";

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public ExampleDao(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

public List<Application> getAllApplications() {
    List<Application> applications = this.jdbcTemplate.query(request, new RowMapper<Application>() {
        @Override
        public Application mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            Application application = new Application();
            application.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            application.setType(rs.getString("type"));
            application.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            application.setDownloads(rs.getInt("downloads"));
            return application;
        }
    });
    return applications;
}
}
```

[image]

Whe I run it and input `http://localhost:8080/details` I have got an 500 exception with stacktrace with this message:

```
root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [jdbc-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jdbc-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Can you explain me how to configure jdbc connection in rigth way or if my approach is correct where I should look for a solution of my issue? All help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring cannot find your jdbc-config.xml configuration file.

You can put it in your classpath instead of the WEB-INF folder and load it in your web.xml like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml,classpath:jdbc-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

A good practice is to create folders main and resources in your src folder and to add them in the classpath. Then you can put the spring config file in the src/resources folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example. Could you explain how to put this files into classpath?

Comment: In IDEA via "Project structure->Modules" I mark WebContent project also as "src". It allows me to refer on jdbc-config.xml and spring-config.xml via classpath but I still have the same issue and erro message.

Comment: In intellij in the Project structure>Modules you have a "Sources" tab. In this tab you can see the source folders at the left and on the right side the module structures. To add a new source folder, right click on the folder to add and click on the Sources entry - there is a button on the top of the right pane called Sources to do the same thing

Comment: Yes, after I have changed code as you said, I am starting get another exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ExampleDao' is defined

But it is the another issue and I should find another answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The class ExempleDao must be a spring bean to use the annotation @Autowired on the datasouce variable.

Answer (score 1):

> class path resource [jdbc-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does
>   not exist

Is the file name correct, where is it located? the file specifying the db connection is not where you said it should be - on the classpath.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain how add this files in classpath? It is not the same such classpath for jdk, right?